# Defining tables - strange bug

Tags: julia

I got a strange kind of issue. When I define this table:

```
function test()

        a = Float32[0.3010299957,0.3010299957,-0.3010299957,0.3010299957,0.3010299957]

    return a[1]*a[3]
end
```

It's fine. After call `test()` i got correct output. But when I define this one, there is an error `ErrorException("−3 not defined")`:

```
function test()

        a = Float32[2.718281828, −3.141592654 , 1.414213562 , 0.5772156649 , 0.3010299957]

    return a[1]*a[2]
end
```

Comment: You are probably using Julia 0.2. In later version you get a better warning about ``invalid character "−"``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using two different dashes: `-` (HYPHEN-MINUS) in the first, and `−` (MINUS SIGN) in the second.  Issues like these often happen when you copy text from a formatted source (web page, document, etc.)  You want to use HYPHEN-MINUS:

```
julia> -1 # hyphen-minus
-1

julia> −1 # minus sign
ERROR: syntax: invalid character "−"
```

Comment: How did you catch that? Bravo

Comment: WOW! I would never find that alone. Thanks a lot!